# Data deleted from db but still exists in redis cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

I am trying to cache a model on my rails app.
I have a model **Snippets**. The first time I create a record, a redis counter cache is created.

**Model**

```
class Snippet < ApplicationRecord
  after_save :clear_cache
  def clear_cache
    $redis.del("snippets")
  end
end
```

**controller**

```
class SnippetsController < ApplicationController
  include SnippetsHelper
  def index
    @snippets = fetch_snippets
  end
  def destroy
    @snippet.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to snippets_url, notice: 'Snippet was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

**view**

```
  <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', snippet_path(snippet["id"]), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
```

So every time I load the index page I load the cache instead of db query.
Now although I have deleted a record in db it still appears on index page. My problem is how do I delete both db record and cache record at the same time.

**redis helper**

```
module SnippetsHelper
  def fetch_snippets
    snippets = $redis.get("snippets")
    if snippets.nil?
      snippets = Snippet.all.to_json
      $redis.set("snippets", snippets)
      $redis.expire("snippets", 5.hour.to_i)
    end
    JSON.load snippets
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code snippet shared above it seems that you clearing the cache only when a data is saved to the database using the callback.

But you also need to update the cache when a data is removed from database.
For this add the callback in model.

```
after_destroy :clear_cache.
```